# Как d PHP код вписать функцию для обработки входных данных?

Tags: php

Как d PHP код вписать функцию для обработки входных данных?

Comment: Используйте шаблон проектирования "фабрика" будет лучше. Посмотреть можно на сайте refactoring.guru

Comment: Это что-то ни то

Comment: Если его корректно применять, то то самое. У вас несколько банков, но с разными параметрами. Фабрика как раз поможет реализовать эту вариативность

Comment: У меня уровень начинающий, о патернах вообще сейчас речь не идет. Возможно я неправильно входной массив составил из условия. Смысл заключается в том, что должно быть две функции, первая - вызывает вторую

Comment: Задача про айпад в кредит?

Comment: Для каждого банка ты получаешь полную сумму выплат за кредит (с процентами), из них нужно выбрать банк с лучшими условиями? Правильно понял?

Comment: Если этот вопрос неактуален, так удали его, не надо здесь чушь писать.

Comment: Актуален, но  я уже несколько дней не могу получить ответ. Получаю всякие вопросы не по теме. А как с этого Оверфлоу удалить вопрос я не знаю